# Why is this swap method not working?

Tags: c++

Why does the below two snippets of code have different results? I want to add a 1 in front of digits, which is a vector of integers. But the second snippet does not properly swap.

```
int tmpInt(1);
for (int i=0; i<digits.size(); i++){
    swap(tmpInt, digits[i]);
}
digits.push_back(tmpInt);
```

versus:

```
int tmpInt(1);
for (auto it : digits){
    swap(tmpInt, it);
}
digits.push_back(tmpInt);
```

Comment: Rhetorical: `int x = 6; int y = x; y = 4; // why is x still 6 instead of 4????`

Comment: I think "it" is not an iterator so maybe you want to change the name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (auto it : digits){
```

The range variable gets essentially copied by value, from the sequence, so

```
   swap(tmpInt, it);
```

all this is doing is swapping between `tmpInt` and a temporary range variable.

You need to use a reference, in order to get equivalent results with the first example:

```
for (auto &it : digits){
   swap(tmpInt, it);
```